# Apply a function to each column with a condition in data.table [R]

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to apply a couple functions to a column but I want to apply some logic as to when I do this, in this case when another column has some NA's. To illustrate I'll add some NA to the `iris` dataset and turn it into a data.table:

```r
library(data.table)

irisdt <- iris
## Prep some example data
irisdt[irisdt$Sepal.Length < 5,]$Sepal.Length <- NA
irisdt[irisdt$Sepal.Width < 3,]$Sepal.Width <- NA

## Turn this into a data.table
irisdt <- as.data.table(iris)
```

If I wanted to apply `max` to multiple columns I'd go like this:

```
## Apply a function to individual columns
irisdt[, lapply(.SD, max), .SDcols = c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")]
#>    Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1:          6.9         2.5
```

In this case however I'd like to take out any row that isn't an NA in `Sepal.Length` and then return max and min along with the name of the column I subset for NA's. Below is an ugly way of implementing this but hopefully illustrates what I am after:

```
## Here is what the table would look like
desired_table <- rbind(
  irisdt[!is.na(Sepal.Length), .(max = max(Petal.Length), min = min(Petal.Length), var = "Sepal.Length")],
  irisdt[!is.na(Sepal.Width), .(max = max(Petal.Length), min = min(Petal.Length), var = "Sepal.Width")]
)

desired_table
#>    max min          var
#> 1: 6.9 1.2 Sepal.Length
#> 2: 6.7 1.0  Sepal.Width
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any thoughts on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`melt` may be better option if we are comparing by multiple columns.  Reshape into 'long' format, then use `i` with the condition `!is.na(value)`, while grouping by 'variable' and get the `min` and `max` of the specified variable

```
library(data.table)
melt(irisdt,  measure = c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width'))[!is.na(value),
   .(max = max(Petal.Length), min = min(Petal.Length)), .(variable)]
```

If we are doing this for multiple variables, then use the `lapply(.SD, ...`

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't actually address the use of logic. That is, for each value of `nm1` I want to further subset each by values that aren't NA.

Comment: @boshek  Sorry, I missed that part.  Corrected

Comment: This is great. This might even be more concise: `melt(irisdt,  measure = c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width'), na.rm = TRUE)[,.(max = max(Petal.Length), min = min(Petal.Length)), .(variable)]`

Comment: @boshek Yes,  I did thought about the `na.rm = TRUE`, but left it to show how we specify the `i`.  It can be any other expression as well